# JQuery AJAX is unable to execute success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

What I'm using: JQuery, mysql_crud.php class

I have a class for donor, inside the class I created a function to add a donor into the database. Any result made by the function will return an array.

donor-class.php

```
public function addDonor($foo, $bar, $soap, ){
    .
    .
    $message = array('message' => 'Message for user here');
    return $message;
}
```

The class is then executed by another php file which will return JSON data

add-donor-function.php

```
$res = $donor->addDonor($foo, $bar, $soap);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($res);
```

This PHP file will return JSON data

```
{
    "message" : "Message for user here"
}
```

I also have a javascript file to run an ajax function

js_add_donor.js

```
function addDonor() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var ic_no = $('#ic_no').val();
    var gender = $('#gender').find(":selected").val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
    var b_type = $('#b_type').find(":selected").val();
    var dob = $('#don').val();
    var address = $('#address').val();
    var district = $('#district').find(":selected").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/firstblood/php/function/donor-management/add-donor-function.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {name:name, ic_no:ic_no, gender:gender, email:email, mobile:mobile, b_type:b_type, dob:dob, address:address, district:district},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result, status){
            // Below codes won't run
            alert('heloo');
            alert(status);
            $('#response').text(success.message);
        }, error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // Below codes run
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(status);
            alert(error);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

addDonor() is used for a button when clicked.
 When the code is executed, the window alerts "200", "parseerror", and "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Where am i wrong here ?

Comment: just check with done: function(result, status) , is that working ?

Comment: It still runs error function. Any idea what might cause the problem? I'm suspecting the json file, but I con't know which part of the codes I need to change

Comment: share your json ??

Comment: already in the question

Comment: Just a wild guess, but did you maybe put another `<` before opening your `<?php` section? I would check your file for any occurrences of `<` since the parser error is pretty specific about it

Comment: maybe instead of `$('#response').text(success.message);` it should be `$('#response').text(result.message);`?

Comment: oh ya I forgot to change to result.message,but I have tried it before, but then it still runs the error function

Comment: Try -  echo json_encode($res, 1);

Comment: remove dataType and try two things: 1. see what happens when it tries to access it 2. if that doesn't work, try JSON.parse(success).message

Comment: @Peter there is no extra `<` in my code

Comment: @AfshanShujat does not work

Comment: @A.Lau not working *crei

Comment: @SyahnurNizam Okay, I cannot help you immediately without seeing your full php-files, but I'm pretty certain that the error is server-side. Somewhere you have an extra `<` where there shouldn't be one. Make sure to check the other files you included as well, since they are able to print to your response as well. In each file there should be exactly one `<` (followed by ?php. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: if you just `console.log(result)` what do you get? Also try removing the `header` from php and repeat my steps and see what happens.

Comment: try after removing - dataType: 'json'